# Running CMD from Java

Tags: java, python, cmd, runtime.exec, processbuilder

```
public void run() {
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = rt.exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe");
        stdin = pr.getOutputStream();
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));
        writer.write("python setup.py py2exe");
        writer.close();
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        String line=null;
        while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am trying to run the line "python setup.py py2exe" in command line via Java, however when I run the code above, it does not work (there are no errors, but the code should create new files in the directory, but it doesn't).

The command runs perfectly if I put it directly into the command prompt.

How can I make this run through Java?

Comment: Have you tried running python directly? What about using cmd /c python?

Comment: Have you tried writing a newline into the stream after the command?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I just tried using `writer.write("cmd /c python") and had no joy. Was that what you meant?

Comment: @Xynariz I just ran `writer.write("python setup.py py2exe\n")` and nothing changed. Any other ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't you want your `OutputStream` to go to `pr`'s `InputStream`?  Similarly, wouldn't you want to read from `pr`'s `OutputStream`?  It seems to me as though you have those backwards.

Comment: @Xynariz The input and output streams have confused me in the past, but I think I've got it the right way round - InputStream is input to the process and OutputStream is output from the process. Also the basic stuff you'd expect a command prompt to output is outputted.

Comment: If you have it correct, why are you trying to *write* to `pr`'s `OutputStream`, and why are you trying to *read* from `pr`'s `InputStream`?  To be clear, you have two processes: the java program, and the command prompt it opens.  You want your java program to write *to the input of* the command prompt, and you want your java program to read *from the output of* the command prompt.

Comment: I just tried switching it, but the arguments for the Buffered constructors don't work out, so I'm pretty sure it is right.

Comment: And I wouldn't get any outputs at all if it was the wrong way round I don't think?

Comment: Upon further investigation, it turns out that the `Process` class' `getInputStream()` method does indeed read from the output, which is VERY POOR NAMING CONVENTION to me.  Given that, I'm at a loss as to what to try next, unless you want to try .flush() instead of .close().  Actually, using .flush() seems a lot more sensible, since you don't really want to close the process until you've read from it.

Comment: Haha I think it's 'VERY POOR NAMING CONVENTION' to everyone! I just tried `writer.flush()` instead but all it does is stops the program from terminating. Thanks a lot for all your help anyway!

Comment: `rt.exec("python");` or `rt.exec("cmd /c python");`

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Comment: the answer below just worked, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use a [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) that way you can use [`inheritIO()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO%28%29) and something like,

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", "setup.py", "py2exe");
pb.inheritIO();
try {
    Process p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor(); // <-- wait for the process to finish
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If I could upvote this I would, but I haven't used stack overflow enough. This worked perfectly, thank you so so much!